# Server Deployment of Economist.com

Tags: deployment

As documented [here](http://drupal.org/node/915102), it seems the Economist is using Drupal for most of it's site.  I am just curious if anyone has information on the number of servers and their config.  Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to learn from this question? Knowing about their configuration won't help you with yours if you don't know WHY they used that configuration. i think you'd get a better answer if you revised to question to include what you're specifically looking to learn about.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about particular website and it will not help any future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have 2 Varnish servers, 10 web servers and 4 database nodes (2 master, 2 slave)

Their workflow is Trunk -> Stage -> Live, from bzr.

They are fully Drupal for a month or so, now.

See [The Economist: An Informal Technical Case Study](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/economist-informal-technical-case-study) session video from DrupalCon London for more information on their processes.